# Add a column based on a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df.

```
data = {
    'policyId': ['X','X','X','X', 'Y','Y','Y','Y', 'Z', 'Z','Z','Z'],
    'element_id': [242, 243, 241, 257, 242, 243, 241, 257, 242, 243, 241, 257],
    'element_selected': [True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

All `policyIds` have the same `element_id`. What changes is that the `element_id` can be select or not (`element_selected` assigns that). I want to add a `contract_type` column to the df. If `element_id`  242 has been selected the `contract_type` should be "CONTENT". If `element_id`  257 has been selected then the `contract_type` should "PRIVATE LIABILITY".  If `element_id` 242 and 257 have both been selected then the `contract_type` should "CONTENT  + PRIVATE LIABILITY".

The problem is that each `policyId` should have only one value per `contract_type` and I do not know how to implement this logic

Expected output

```
policyId    element_id  element_selected    contract_type
X                  242  True                CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
X                  243  True                CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
X                  241  True                CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
X                  257  True                CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
Y                  242  False               PRIVATE LIABILITY
Y                  243  True                PRIVATE LIABILITY
Y                  241  True                PRIVATE LIABILITY
Y                  257  True                PRIVATE LIABILITY
Z                  242  True                CONTENT
Z                  243  True                CONTENT
Z                  241  True                CONTENT
Z                  257  False               CONTENT
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _"All `policyIds` have the same `element_id`"_?

Comment: I wanted to say that `policyIds` always have the same records for `element_id`. For instance, in the small example I provided, all `policyIds` have the same 242, 243, 241 and 257 records for `element_id`

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

Pivot the dataframe

```
s = df.pivot(index='policyId', columns='element_id', values='element_selected')

# element_id   241    242   243    257
# policyId                            
# X           True   True  True   True
# Y           True  False  True   True
# Z           True   True  True  False
```

Use np.select to select the choices based on predefined conditions

```
s['contract_type'] = np.select(
    [s[[242, 257]].all(axis=1), s[242], s[257]],
    ["CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY", "CONTENT", "PRIVATE LIABILITY"]
)

# element_id   241    242   243    257                contract_type
# policyId                                                         
# X           True   True  True   True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
# Y           True  False  True   True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
# Z           True   True  True  False                      CONTENT
```

Map the selected choices back to dataframe

```
df['contract_type'] = df['policyId'].map(s['contract_type'])

#    policyId  element_id  element_selected                contract_type
# 0         X         242              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 1         X         243              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 2         X         241              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 3         X         257              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 4         Y         242             False            PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 5         Y         243              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 6         Y         241              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 7         Y         257              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
# 8         Z         242              True                      CONTENT
# 9         Z         243              True                      CONTENT
# 10        Z         241              True                      CONTENT
# 11        Z         257             False                      CONTENT
```

Comment: I like the pivoting and mapping ideas, they are cool! As of the middle part, I believe it should be better, no? IMO hardcoding `"CONTENT + PRIVATE RESPONSIBILITY"` doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a groupy "policyId" and then implement a mapping function that does the logic of assigning the contract_type:

```py
def get_contract_type(group):
    types = []
    # get selected ids
    ids = list(group[group["element_selected"]]["element_id"])

    # add the types based on the selected ids
    if 242 in ids:
        types.append("CONTENT")

    if 257 in ids:
       types.append("PRIVATE LIABILITY")


    # add the new contract_type column
    group["contract_type"] = " + ".join(types)
    return group

df.groupby("policyId").apply(get_contract_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create a temporary column that contains zeros:

```
df["contract_type"] = 0
```

The purpose of initializing this column to zeros will become clear later in this answer.

Now, group by `policyId`:

```
policy_groups = df.groupby("policyId")
```

Next, for each group, filter out the rows where `element_selected` is `False`, and see if `242` and `257` exist in the `element_id` column. If `242` exists, let's add `1` to `contract_type` for all rows in the group. If `257` exists, let's add `2`.

```
for policy_id, group in policy_groups:
    selected_ids = group.loc[group["element_selected"], "element_id"]
    if (selected_ids == 242).any():
        df.loc[group.index, "contract_type"] += 1
    if (selected_ids == 257).any():
        df.loc[group.index, "contract_type"] += 2
```

At this stage, `df` looks like:

```
   policyId  element_id  element_selected  contract_type
0         X         242              True              3
1         X         243              True              3
2         X         241              True              3
3         X         257              True              3
4         Y         242             False              2
5         Y         243              True              2
6         Y         241              True              2
7         Y         257              True              2
8         Z         242              True              1
9         Z         243              True              1
10        Z         241              True              1
11        Z         257             False              1
```

Now that this is complete for all groups, we can map the integers in the `contract_type` column to the required strings:

```
df["contract_type"] = df["contract_type"].map({0: "", 1: "CONTENT", 2: "PRIVATE LIABILITY", 3: "CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY"})
```

And we have the required dataframe:

```
   policyId  element_id  element_selected                contract_type
0         X         242              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
1         X         243              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
2         X         241              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
3         X         257              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
4         Y         242             False            PRIVATE LIABILITY
5         Y         243              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
6         Y         241              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
7         Y         257              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
8         Z         242              True                      CONTENT
9         Z         243              True                      CONTENT
10        Z         241              True                      CONTENT
11        Z         257             False                      CONTENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(df.assign(contract_type = df['policyId']
           .map(df['element_id'].map({242:'0',257:'1'})
                .where(df['element_selected'])
                .str.get_dummies()
                .groupby(df['policyId']).any()
                .mul([1,2])
                .sum(axis=1)
                .map(dict(enumerate(['NEITHER','CONTENT','PRIVATE LIABILITY','CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY']))))))
```

or

```
df.assign(
    contract_type = (df['policyId'].map(
        df['element_id']
        .sort_values()
        .map(
            {242:'CONTENT',257:'PRIVATE LIABILITY'})
            .where(df['element_selected'] & ~df.duplicated(subset = ['policyId','element_id']))
            .dropna()
            .groupby(df['policyId'])
            .agg(' + '.join))))
```

Output:

```
   policyId  element_id  element_selected                contract_type
0         X         242              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
1         X         243              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
2         X         241              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
3         X         257              True  CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY
4         Y         242             False            PRIVATE LIABILITY
5         Y         243              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
6         Y         241              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
7         Y         257              True            PRIVATE LIABILITY
8         Z         242              True                      CONTENT
9         Z         243              True                      CONTENT
10        Z         241              True                      CONTENT
11        Z         257             False                      CONTENT
```

Comment: Can you explain how you get `CONTENT + PRIVATE LIABILITY` case? By reading the code is straightforward for the other cases but for this one I did not get how it works

Comment: I made some slight changes just in case your real data is organized differently. If a policy has both content and private liability, those two strings will be joined by the + sign.

Comment: Could you please explain, why do you need the condition `~df.duplicated(subset=['policyId','element_id'])`?

Comment: just in case there are multiple of the same element_id's. If 242 was present twice in X, it would become CONTENT + CONTENT

Comment: @rhug123 I think it's not the case, because otherwise this might cause a confusion be there two `X, 242` with different `element_selected`. But anyway, I got the point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Let's do it with CategoricalDtype

```py
ContractTypes = {
    242: 'Content',
    257: 'Private liability'
}

contract_type = (
    df.set_index('policyId')
    .product('columns')
    .astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(ContractTypes))
    .cat.rename_categories(ContractTypes.values())
    .dropna()
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(' + '.join)
    .rename('contract_type')
)

df = df.set_index('policyId').join(contract_type).reset_index()
```

First we create a dictionary of contract type codes as keys and associated descriptions. With time we may want to add a new contract type here without mitigating with the rest of the code.

Next we create a series `contract_type`:

- put `policyId` as an index for further grouping by index;
- product along the rows returns zero in place of *false* codes;
- transforming the result to categorical `ContractTypes` will replace unused contract types with `NaN`, which in turn we can safely discard, since the data we have is tied to the `policyId` index;
- next we rename categories with their associated descriptions;
- now we group the rest of the data by index (i.e. `level=0`) and join them together with `' + '` in between;
- finally we give the sequence a name which will become a name of a column after further joining with `df`.

## Let's do it by Pivoting

```py
ContractTypes = pd.Series({
    242: 'Content',
    257: 'Private liability'
})

selected = df.pivot(
    index='policyId',
    columns='element_id',
    values='element_selected'
).apply(
    lambda s: ' + '.join(ContractTypes[s]), 
    axis='columns'
)

df['contract_type'] = df['policyId'].map(selected)
```

This one is an upgraded version of the [Shubham Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76805795/14909621).
The only change is made in the middle, where each row of the pivoted data is used as an index in the ContractTypes series, and obtained descriptions are joined in a string.